# How to adjust socket descriptors?

Tags: rabbitmq

[image]

I want to know who to adjust quantity of the socket descriptors?

In addition, how to auto-close the connection for limited timeout?

Comment: Do you want increase the value ?  Do you use the heartbeat ?

Comment: I want to know where  "829 restriction" come from and how to adjust it. And I will try Heartbeat today later. Thanks

Comment: Please, specify which OS you are running RabbitMQ on.

Comment: Linux 10-4-1-4 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Is there a reason the number of default socket descriptors is such a small value? If it is increased to 4000, what does it mean? Does it mean RabbitMQ will take more memory? Will it take more time for it to loop through all descriptors when processing data? What are the implications of increasing the value?

Answer (score 23):

Looks like you have to change max opened file descriptors in your system.

From RabbitMQ installation manual for Debian and Ubuntu systems, section [Controlling system limits](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#kernel-resource-limits):

> RabbitMQ installations running production workloads may need system
>   limits and kernel parameters tuning in order to handle a decent number
>   of concurrent connections and queues. The main setting that needs
>   adjustment is the max number of open files, also known as ulimit -n.
>   The default value on many operating systems is too low for a messaging
>   broker (eg. 1024 on several Linux distributions). We recommend
>   allowing for at least 65536 file descriptors for user rabbitmq in
>   production environments. 4096 should be sufficient for most
>   development workloads.
>
> There are two limits in play: the maximum number of open files the OS
>   kernel allows (*fs.file-max*) and the per-user limit (*ulimit -n*). The
>   former must be higher than the latter.
>
> The most straightforward way to adjust the per-user limit for RabbitMQ
>   is to edit the */etc/default/rabbitmq-server* (provided by the RabbitMQ
>   Debian package) or [rabbitmq-env.conf](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) to invoke ulimit before the
>   service is started.
>
> `ulimit -S -n 4096`
>
> This soft limit cannot go higher than the hard limit (which defaults
>   to 4096 in many distributions). [The hard limit can be increased](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Linux) via
>   */etc/security/limits.conf*. This also requires enabling the
>   [pam_limits.so](https://askubuntu.com/a/34559) module and re-login or reboot.
>
> Note that limits cannot be changed for running OS processes.
>
> For more information about controlling *fs.file-max* with *sysctl*, please
>   refer to the excellent [Riak guide on open file limit tuning](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Linux).

P.S.:

The similar issue was discussed in RabbitMQ mailing list "[Increasing the file descriptors limit](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-January/025007.html)". The last message contains final link to the RabbitMQ installation document and explicitly point to ulimit issue, but reading through it also may help you to deal with you problem while the whole thread covers the descriptors limit issue from different points.

Comment: This works for me. Thank you. But what I'm confusing is that what's the difference between this way and modifying  `/etc/security/limits.conf`?

Comment: This question citing a bit outdated doc page. I just updated answer: `This soft limit cannot go higher than the hard limit (which defaults to 4096 in many distributions). The hard limit can be increased via /etc/security/limits.conf.`

Answer (score 11):

I am running RabbitMQ 3.6.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 and with those newer versions the answer given here (using ulimit in the rabbitmq-server file) no longer worked for me.

The solution for me was to configure the limits for systemd in this file

/etc/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service.d/override.conf

In that file, put this configuration

`[Service]
LimitNOFILE=32768`

Where 32768 is the number of file handles you want to configure.

If you edit that file directly, you'll need to reload the systemd configuration with

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

But you can also use systemctl to edit the file, in which case it reloads the configuration automatically

`sudo systemctl edit rabbitmq-server`

Comment: this is the only method that works for ubuntu 16 and rabbitmq 3.6.3

Comment: I can confirm that the systemd service on Ubuntu 16.04 does not source the `/etc/default/rabbitmq-server` file, so adding the ulimit line in there does not work. This systemd override works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the other answers here do answer the question of how to raise the limit of socket descriptors (setting `ulimit -n <value>` in `/etc/default/rabbitmq-server`), but none of them answered your other question (Why 829 socket descriptors when the file descriptor limit is 1024?)

This is due to the number of other file handles that RabbitMQ is using. You will always have a lower number of socket descriptors by some degree (From my own usage, it's around 90-95% of the file descriptor limit). RabbitMQ's documentation provides the recommendation that you set your file descriptor limit to 1.5 times the number of connections you expect to have at a maximum: [Tuning For A Large Number of Connections](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#tuning-for-large-number-of-connections)

Answer (score 3):

you can add following line in /etc/security/limits.conf

```
* soft nofile 65000
* hard nofile 65000
```

with this  you set ulimit to 65000

Answer (score 2):

The solution which worked for me on Ubuntu is [this](https://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-January/025007.html):

First, find the correct `rabbitmq-server` file. You can do this by running `locate rabbitmq-server` on the bash prompt.
Then open the file with `sudo vim /etc/default/rabbitmq-server`. It is a file which will contain the line `ulimit -n 4096`.
If the line is commented out with a `#`, uncomment the line.
Then add `EOF` as the last line of the file.

The file will now appear like this:

```
# This file is sourced by /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server. Its primary
# reason for existing is to allow adjustment of system limits for the
# rabbitmq-server process.
#
# Maximum number of open file handles. This will need to be increased
# to handle many simultaneous connections. Refer to the system
# documentation for ulimit (in man bash) for more information.
#
ulimit -n 4096
EOF
```

Now you have to restart rabbitmq. Don't restart the operating system though.
Locate your `rabbitmqctl` file and run:
`sudo /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop`
Then start rabbitmq again either with `sudo /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl start &`.

That's it. Now go to the RabbitMQ Browser UI, and you'll see that the number of sockets have increased.

Comment: For some reason I had to restart using `service rabbitmq-server restart` for the changes to take effect, otherwise my old settings were being used. The other steps worked perfectly on RabbitMQ 3.5.7