# How do I free socket descriptors in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I've got a RabbitMQ that talks to a bunch of services. One of these is a log daemon that eats a lot of socket descriptors and it looks like it's not freing them up. Because of that, the job I want to run now (which needs one) is not starting since it cannot talk to the queue.

**How do I kill connections from the RabbitMQ web frontend?**

I do not want increase the number of file descriptors in the filesystem (as described in [How to adjust socket descriptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577809/how-to-adjust-socket-descriptors)). What I want is to get rid of open ones that are dead and not purged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From web management panel you can open Connections tab, then manually select connection and Force Close it.

Alternatively, you can close connections from cli, see ["Close all connections" section of rabbitmqadmin manual](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html).